# Escape chars in R's readLines

Tags: r, regex, xml

I am reading XPath-Expressions from an XML-File using `readLines` and `xmlTreeParse`, `xmlToList` from the `XML` package.

In my XML file there is a line with an XPath like

```
//*[(@id = "name")]              (1)
```

The functions mentioned above always add escape chars to my XPath which turns them to

```
"//*[(@id = \"name\")]"          (2)
```

How can I convert (2) back to (1)?

I already tried:

- `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode`
- `gsub` with "\" as pattern which leads to an "Trailing backslash" error
- `gsub` with "[\]" which changes nothing
- some variations of the above using `intToUtf8()`
- adding escape `\` to my XML file

Comment: You're confusing the default object `print()` output with the actual data in the character vector. Try `print(name_of_your_character_vector, quote=FALSE)` or `cat(name_of_your_character_vector, sep="\n")` to prove it. You can even do `charToRaw(name_of_your_character_vector[1])` (or any index) to see the hex strings. A backslash is `5c`. There won't be any.

Comment: There is nothing to convert, you have `"`s, and not ``\"`` in your strings

Comment: I guess I'm having a different problem with my XPath expressions then as they don't work when passed to my function. Thanks for your help.